rpId validation failed in Passkeys PoC on Android using Jetpack Compose
I am working on a Passkeys Proof of Concept (PoC) for an Android app using Jetpack Compose. I've set up the required digital asset links (assetlinks.json) and domain verification for app-to-web authentication. Despite following the setup, I am encountering an error related to rpid validation failed when attempting to use passkeys.
I'm creating a passkey through the browser and then trying to use it in the native app.
Here’s what I’ve done:
Verified my domain using adb shell pm get-app-links my.package.example, which returns:
my.package.example:
  ID: 09699a58-4970-4dd8-8f30-323c5c792297
  Signatures: [CF:BF:CC:4C:AF:28:CF:82:35:F9:9D:D0:F5:C6:14:1A:AC:CF:E9:50:AA:12:25:80:E5:1D:BD:60:1E:04:21:53]
  Domain verification state:
    my.domain.com: 1024

Here’s my assetlinks.json:
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds",
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "my.package.example",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "CF:BF:CC:4C:AF:28:CF:82:35:F9:9D:D0:F5:C6:14:1A:AC:CF:E9:50:AA:12:25:80:E5:1D:BD:60:1E:04:21:53"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
            "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "web",
            "site": "https://my.domain.com"
        }
    }
]

My AndroidManifest.xml includes an intent-filter with android:autoVerify="true":
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="my.domain.com" />
</intent-filter>

The domain is correctly included in the strings as well:
<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">
  [{\"include\": \"https://my.domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"}]
</string>


I am passing the rpId in my JSON request:
val requestJson = JSONObject().apply {
    put("challenge", authorizationResponse.metadata.challenge)
    put("rpId", "my.domain.com")
    put("allowCredentials", JSONArray())
    put("timeout", 18000)
    put("userVerification", "required")
}

Despite all of this, I am still getting the following error:
rpId validation failed
and can't verify the domain using pm get-app-links my.package.example
Domain verification state:
my.domain.com: 1024

You don't include your actual domain, so I can't check for you, but you can query the underlying service to check your domain's status:
curl 'https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/assetlinks:check?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls&target.android_app.package_name=PACKAGE_NAME&target.android_app.certificate.sha256_fingerprint=APK_CERTIFICATE_FINGERPRINT'

Be sure to replace PACKAGE_NAME and APK_CERTIFICATE_FINGERPRINT, of course. The latter should be in hex-with-colons format, as you have above.

Thanks for your response! Currently the site is not public, so I can only access it inside my private network. The android emulator (and also I tried installing the app on my own mobile) can acces the json using a browser without ant problem

Note that Google Password Manager uses that Google service to check assetlinks.json files. I.e. assetlinks.json must be available publicly to function.

OMG thank you so much! Reading the documentation I didn't understand that the assetlinks must be available publicly. Can you re write this comment as a different answer so I can mark it as the response?
